# How to auto add more blank lines to bottom when editing?

Tags: vim

like `scrolloff`, but it will reach bottom
I want it never reach bottom of the edit area although move the cursor to the bottom of text.

```
100 func coding
101     return coding
102 end
103 // bottom of file
~   
~   auto added, can't reach
~
=============status bar===========
```

Comment: I didn't get what you want, can you explain it in a bit more detail?

Comment: You can hit `zz` when the cursor is on the last line.

Comment: @romainl my understanding is he wants to disable all motion/command which **could** bring cursor to last line, like `G`, `j`, `L` ... but not sure about that

Comment: @Kent yes, when goto last line , vim append some lines to bottom .

Comment: @kran: You know that they are not added lines, only representing "nothing"? Are your question that you don't want to see that at all, that the last line of the file should be also the last shown line in the window? In that case (as long as there are more lines in the file than in the window) I think there is a way to do it. But the best solution would be: get used to it. Or `Ctrl-E` and `Ctrl-Y` will help you?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
:autocmd CursorMoved * if line('.') == line('$') | call append('$', '') | endif
```

It will automatically append an empty line whenever the cursor reaches the last line.

Comment: What exactly do you do? It appends an empty line when I reach then end, e.g. via `jjjj` or `G`. If you want this while in insert mode, append the `,CursorMovedI` event.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you could combine the comment by *244an* and *Ingo Karkat's* answer to have vim always leave some empty lines at the bottom of its window. The following should get you part of the way:

```
autocmd CursorMoved * 
  \ if line('.') > line('$') - &scrolloff 
  \ && line('w0') + winheight(0) - 1 - &scrolloff < line('$') 
  \ | exec 'normal ^R' 
  \ | endif
```

Note that there are a couple of issues with this:

- This also applies to the command window.
- If you jump directly to the bottom of the file, new skips will be done until `scrolloff` lines are visible below the last line.